# Fixing the IV for JCE RSA Encryption

Tags: java, rsa, public-key-encryption, jce

I'm trying to pass an RSA Key generated in JS to encrypt something in Java. We're passing the exponent and the modulus and then generating a key from that.

However when encrypting in JCE, two ciphertexts are never the same because the initialization creates a random IV, as directed.

Is there some way to fix the IV for initiliazation so the Javascript can pass it to the Java server? The documentation for the JCE gives me nothing.

Thanks in advance, its much appreciated.

EDIT: its come to my attention that the IV is used for the padding. I'm using PKCS1 padding, if that changes anything.

EDIT: I've done some more reading, and apparently the difference between the ciphertexts is due to the padding. While I appreciate that this is working as directed, I need the client to be able to decrypt the encrypted text. If I pass it the ciphertext encrypted with the public key, will the client be able to decrypt it even without knowing anything about the padding, even if its a different library and language doing the decrypting?

Comment: The is no IV for RSA. Perhaps you mean the random padding. You need to validate your code by encrypting in JS and decrypting in Java and then the other way around. Don't rely on solely on the encryption to produce the came ciphertext.

Comment: The JCE requires you to give a block cipher mode for the RSA algorithm (specifically CBC). Is it actually implementing RSA on a randomly generated AES key and then encrypting the plaintext with that RSA Key?

I'm aware that this is the standard method of implementing RSA, but that is exactly what I'm trying to do. If thats what is happening, is it possible to purely implement RSA and ignore the AES parts?

If the IV is used for the padding, I'm using PKCS1 padding if that helps. Is there some way to extract that IV?

Comment: The normal "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding" is RSA with padding and without AES. This also doesn't use an IV. Maybe you're talking about RSA-KEM?